# Is there any way, to send a notification from Flash Air card to Android App on any update?

Tags: java, android, ios, c, flashair

I'm working on android project. I have made android application which gets the files from FlashAir wifi storage card. Using `polling` method, I refresh file list and then I check if any file is updated or not, but I need notification from server(FlashAir) side and not from application side when any file gets updated means I dn't wanna use polling method on application side.

Answer (score 1):

you can use broadcast receiver to push notifications
look http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-broadcast-receiver-notification-tutorial/